# How to show response json of validation errors in Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-10, laravel-api

I'm working with Laravel and this is my RegisterController Class based on API:

```
class RegisterController extends AuthController
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|max:13|same:password_confirmation',
        ]);

        $errors = [];
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            foreach($validator->errors()->all() as $err){
                array_push($errors, $err);
            }

            return view('auth.index', compact('errors'));
        }else{
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
            ]);

            Auth::login($user);

            $token = $user->createToken('API Token')->accessToken;

            return response()->json(['token' => $token], 201);
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine but as you see I tried showing validation errors by returning the view and compacted the errors array to it:

```
return view('auth.index', compact('errors'));
```

This is wrong, however, I don't know how to capture the response json for the error showing.

So if you know how to do this, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want json validation response ?  if not then share blade file

Comment: since this is api, you might be using ajax./axios or anything equivalent. did you try to console.log the response? Check the contents of response

Comment: First of all, why are you foreaching the errors and putting them in an other array? And you are returning a view, not a json response. It is strange that you return a json on success and a view on error.

Comment: @JohnLobo I want to use this for sending api requests and also use that as action of my form in blade,

Comment: Directly use `->validate` instead of `make`... read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic)...

Answer (score 3):

[Automatic Redirection](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#automatic-redirection)

> If you would like to create a validator instance manually but still
> take advantage of the automatic redirection offered by the HTTP
> request's validate method, you may call the validate method on an
> existing validator instance. If validation fails, the user will
> automatically be redirected or, in the case of an XHR request, a JSON
> response will be returned:

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|max:13|same:password_confirmation',
        ])->validate();
```

or

```
$request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|max:13|same:password_confirmation',
        ])
```

So if the request contains header `content-type:application/json` then it automatically converts to JSON.In Blade you can do the following

```
@error('name')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

or

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```